# Cant figure out why my character, word and line count will work with file input but not from stdin

Tags: c, unix

Im pretty new to C programming and I am having trouble with stdin. My code is supposed to display the number of words, lines and characters contained in an input file or standard input. If its displaying the numbers from a file, then the name of the file needs to be along side of the number of words, lines and characters like so:

> 0     0     0    test.txt

I am able to do this but then stdin will not work and I get 
"Segmentation Fault (core dumped)"

```css
enum state
{
  START,
  WORD,
  DELIM,
};

FILE *
input_from_args(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  if (argc == 1){
    return stdin;
  } else {
    return fopen(argv[1], "r");
  }
}

void
wcount(FILE *src, FILE *dest, const char *argv[])
{
  int ch, wc, lc, cc;
  enum state cstate;

  wc = lc = cc = 0;
  cstate = START;
  while ((ch = fgetc(src)) != EOF){
    cc++;
    switch (cstate){
    case START:
      if (isspace(ch)){
 cstate = DELIM;
 if (ch == '\n'){
   lc++;
 }
      } else{
 cstate = WORD;
 wc++;
      }
      break;
    case DELIM:
      if (ch == '\n'){
 lc++;
      } else if (!isspace(ch)){
 cstate = WORD;
 wc++;
      }
      break;
    case WORD:
      if (isspace(ch)){
 cstate = DELIM;
 if (ch == '\n'){
   lc++;
 }
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  fprintf(dest, "%d\t%d\t%d\t%s\n", wc, lc, cc, argv[1]);
}
```

I have a feeling the reason I'm running into this problem has to do with the argv[] in my wcount function.

Sorry for the wall of text in this post, I'm new to this site and don't exactly know how I should be posting questions. Thanks

edit: the file is specified after I compile and run the program.

So i say

```
./tstats test.txt
```

and it displays

```
0    0    0    test.txt
```

Comment: First thing I notice (last line): argv[1] is only valid if you specified a file. If you did not, argv[1] is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
void wcount(FILE *src, FILE *dest, const char *argv[])
```

You get the argument `argv` just to use it at

```
fprintf(dest, "%d\t%d\t%d\t%s\n", wc, lc, cc, argv[1]);
```

But you use it without checking if it actually exists, something you **did** do in the `input_from_args` function.

So you either pass `argc` as an argument for `wcount` too and do:

```
if (argc == 1) {
    fprintf(dest, "%d\t%d\t%d\tstdin\n", wc, lc, cc); // no argv[1]
else {
    fprintf(dest, "%d\t%d\t%d\t%s\n", wc, lc, cc, argv[1]);
}
```

Or you pass instead of `argv` a `char* filename` argument, that you check outside of the call of `wcount`, and proceed with a

```
fprintf(dest, "%d\t%d\t%d\t%s\n", wc, lc, cc, filename);
```

call.